# Missing integration constants in solution to PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am attempting to obtain the analytical solution (if possible) to the following:

$$a w^{(1,0)}(x,t)+b w^{(0,1)}(x,t)=p(x)+g  w(x,t)$$
$$I.C.: w(x,0)=0 | B.C.: w(0,t)=z(t)$$

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = v;
b = 1;
g = -\[Lambda];
p = \[Psi]*Cos[Pi*x];
ic = w[x, 0] == 0;
bc = w[0, t] == z[t];
pde = a*D[w[x, t], x] + b*D[w[x, t], t] == g*w[x, t] + p
DSolve[pde, w[x, t], {x, t}]
```

$$\left\{\left\{w(x,t)\to \frac{e^{-\frac{\lambda  x}{v}} \left(\pi ^2 v^2 c_1\left(\frac{t v-x}{v}\right)+\lambda ^2 c_1\left(\frac{t v-x}{v}\right)+\pi  v \psi  \sin (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}+\lambda  \psi  \cos (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}\right)}{\lambda ^2+\pi ^2 v^2}\right\}\right\}$$

However, the solution returned only has 1 integration constant, `c_1`, rather than the 2 I expected (i.e., an initial condition and a boundary condition). Thus, when I attempt the next step to apply the conditions I can only apply one, leading to an erroneous/incomplete solution.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Using v11.2.

**Update**

Apparently `c_1` is really a function and not a constant. In that case I am still left wondering how to proceed. There is a soluction when solving for IC **OR** BC but not both. Ideas/tricks on how to proceed?

```
DSolve[{pde, ic}, w[x, t], {x, t}]
```

$$\left\{\left\{w(x,t)\to \frac{\psi  e^{-\frac{\lambda  x}{v}} \left(-\pi  v e^{\frac{\lambda  (x-t v)}{v}} \sin (\pi  (x-t v))-\lambda  e^{\frac{\lambda  (x-t v)}{v}} \cos (\pi  (x-t v))+\pi  v \sin (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}+\lambda  \cos (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}\right)}{\lambda ^2+\pi ^2 v^2}\right\}\right\}$$

```
DSolve[{pde, bc}, w[x, t], {x, t}]
```

$$\left\{\left\{w(x,t)\to \frac{e^{-\frac{\lambda  x}{v}} \left(-\lambda  \psi +\pi ^2 v^2 z\left(\frac{t v-x}{v}\right)+\lambda ^2 z\left(\frac{t v-x}{v}\right)+\pi  v \psi  \sin (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}+\lambda  \psi  \cos (\pi  x) e^{\frac{\lambda  x}{v}}\right)}{\lambda ^2+\pi ^2 v^2}\right\}\right\}$$

```
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, w[x, t], {x, t}]
```

$$\text{DSolve}\left[\left\{v w^{(1,0)}(x,t)+w^{(0,1)}(x,t)=\psi  \cos (\pi  x)-\lambda  w(x,t),w(x,0)=0,w(0,t)=z(t)\right\},w(x,t),\{x,t\}\right]$$

Comment: You get function `c1[t]`,  not only a constant!

Comment: If you look at the `StandardForm` or `FullForm` of the solution you can see that `C[1]` is an arbitray function rather than an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would have never guessed that.

Comment: Do the IC and BC apply to *all* values of $x$ and $t$, or just $x >0$ and $t > 0$?  If it's the latter, then I think the ICs and BCs can be both be satisfied.  If the former, they probably can't.  (The solution along any characteristic is determined by its intersections with the IC and/or BC surface, and if the characteristics intersect said surfaces more than once, the solutions are overdetermined.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, yes it is just for x>0 and t>0

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I'm assuming that $v > 0$ (if not, then my argument about the characteristics doesn't hold.)

Comment: Note that the code *does* work if you replace `z[t]` with a known function such as `Sin[t]`.

Comment: Indeed $v>0$. And yes you are right. It does work when I replace z[t] with a constant or some recognized time dependent function. At some point this was tried, but clearly I have changed something along the way. In any case thank you.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert although your suggestion was super simple. It technically was the answer. If you would like credit go ahead and post it so I can accept it and "close" this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Mathematica does not seem to be able to solve the problem for a general unknown boundary condition $w(0,t) = z(t)$, it can generally solve it if $z(t)$ is replaced by a known function such as $\sin(t)$:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = v;
b = 1;
g = -\[Lambda];
p = \[Psi]*Cos[Pi*x];
ic = w[x, 0] == 0;
bc = w[0, t] == Sin[t];
pde = a*D[w[x, t], x] + b*D[w[x, t], t] == g*w[x, t] + p
DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, w[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Replacing $z(t)$ with a polynomial also results in a solution fairly quickly.  I also tried $z(t) = \ln(1+t)$, which took longer but did eventually return a solution as well.

Comment: Disclaimer:  I believe this is the code I used when I tested it out two days ago.  But I've got both my Mathematica kernels working on another problem right now and so I haven't personally tested this version.  It should work, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I double checked it and it works.